# How Springboot manages beans in distributed system?

Tags: java, spring-boot, distributed-system

Lets says I have an app in spring boot. There are several instances of this app will be running in a distributed system to handle a large number of request coming from various users. Spring will create/manage its beans in the application context. There are several instances of the App with application contexts that will be running. If we have a load balancer sitting in front of this app and it distributes the requests on each instance, then how spring will manage the beans.

Comment: Every node in a distributed system is a separate app instance. Each instance has its own bean pool, there is no sharing between them.

Comment: Every individual instance of app will have its own Application Context and it will be responsible for the bean management.How you distribute your network requests is independent of bean creation.

Answer (score 0):

With a load balancer alone in front of your application instances, spring boot applications will not be aware of each other.
There won`t be any bean management between instances and ach instance will maintain its own application context and managed beans.
You can explicitly connect instances together to use the same database as a data source or persistent session (server.session.persistent=true) so that session is not lost when the load balancer routes to the other node.